# Setting `PYTHONPATH` for an Open Source Shiny Server Deployment

Tags: shiny, pythonpath, py-shiny

I was trying to set up an open source shiny-python server following the instructions [here](https://shiny.posit.co/py/docs/deploy-on-prem.html#deploy-to-shiny-server-open-source). However, the shiny server does not seem to read the system's `PYTHONPATH`. Is there a way I can set the `PYTHONPATH` for the shiny server in the config file?